# GPUImage crop square with 16:9 aspect ratio

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I am using the following code

```
if(cameraPosition == 1){

        _stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];

        _cropFilter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.109f, 1.f, .75f)];

    }else {

        _stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];

        _cropFilter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.125f, 1.f, .75f)];

    }
```

The else works great when cropping an image using the 4S camera and a 4:3 image. The problem is that I am trying to set it so that it crops a square for all the other IPhones which are 16:9. I have tried to create a new region without any success.

Comment: Are GPUImage's crop regions the opposite way around from the dimensions implied by the session presets? Otherwise the fact that you appear to take a 4:3 input of 640x480, then crop it to 1.0 times the width and 0.75 times the height to get a square image seems very confusing. If it were 1 times height and 0.75 times width that'd make more sense — 3/4 * 4/3 is clearly 1.

Comment: @ORStudios did you find a solution?